# PHP . Mysql - Method not updating mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I m not sure why this method is not updating the `pending` row in `items`

```
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default     | Extra
| pending       | int(1)       | YES  |     | NULL        |
```

function:

```
private function setPendingWin($item_id)
{
    var_dump($item_id);
    if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE items SET pending = 1 WHERE id = ?"))
    {
        $q->bind_param("i", $item_id);
        $q->execute();
        $a_r = $q->affected_rows;
        $q->close();

        return $a_r;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: What if you just say `UPDATE items SET pending = 1`? does it work? If yes then check your where condition.

Comment: `$this->db->mysqli->prepare` wooops.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of execute() ?

Comment: post var_dump($q->execute()); too plz!

Comment: `var_dump($q->execute());` - `bool(true)`

Comment: @Rahul taking off the where condition works. But I need it to update for a particular item. And var_dump($item_id); is the an id. Why wouldn't it work with the where condition?

Comment: Ok ... figured it out. I was doing this: `return $this->db->mysqli->insert_id;` and expecting to get the item id ... but it was returning the last row id from some other table ... i'll just pass the id some other way. Thank you all.

Comment: @ciprian, I have posted it as answer to give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just say `UPDATE items SET pending = 1?` does it work? If yes then check your where condition. I am trying to point out that the where condition `WHERE id = ?` doesn't matches any record and so no update is happening.

If you want to validate the same then perform a `SELECT` query with same condition and see how many records does it fetches

```
SELECT * from items WHERE id = ?
```